# Finding a file using grep

Tags: grep

I want to find file containing some interesting stuff for me. I want that file to have extension .h or .cc. Is there some faster way than typing two times:

```
grep -r "some stuff" * --include="*.h"
grep -r "some stuff" * --include="*.cc"
```

?

Comment: i find it ; ) grep -r "some stuff" * --include="*.h" --include="*.cc"

Answer (score 0):

I have a bash function defined in my .bashrc which searches in the current directory recursively but skips files and directories known to not be of interest:

```
function cgrep () {
    egrep -nrI --color=auto --exclude="*.svn-base" --exclude=".svn" --exclude="entries" --exclude=".*.d" --exclude="cscope.out" --exclude="*.syms" --exclude="*.dis" --exclude="*.d" "$@" .
}
```

Call it via

```
> cgrep uint64_t
./fs/nfsd/nfs4xdr.c:3016:   uint64_t minor_id = 0;
./fs/nfs/callback.h:67: uint64_t size;
./fs/nfs/callback.h:68: uint64_t change_attr;
./fs/nfs/fscache-index.c:188:                      uint64_t *size)
```

The searched pattern is actually colored! :-)